# debug of plugin-mathjax of gitbook

Tags: debugging, plugins, mathjax

When I want to display math formula with plugin-mathjax of Gitbook,it debugs even I follow following tips.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.c)
Add it to my book.json configuration:

```
{
"plugins": ["mathjax"]
}
```

Install plugins using:

```
$ gitbook install ./
```

Finally it fails:

```
info: installing plugin "mathjax"
runTopLevelLifecycles ->  | |######################################################################################---|
fetchMetadata -> headers  \ |##################################################################-----------------------|
C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\aproba\index.js:25
    if (args[ii] == null) throw missingRequiredArg(ii)
                          ^

Error: Missing required argument #1
    at andLogAndFinish (C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
    at fetchPackageMetadata (C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
    at resolveWithNewModule (C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:490:12)
    at C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:491:7
    at C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
    at C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
    at addRequestedAndFinish (C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:67:5)
    at returnAndAddMetadata (C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:121:7)
    at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:138:20)
    at C:\Users\Meng\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50 {
  code: 'EMISSINGARG'
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wi9V.png)
My computer’s operate system is win10,node’s version is v16.5.0, npm version is 7.19.1.

```
PS D:\git_books> node -v
v16.5.0
PS D:\git_books> npm -v
7.19.1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUN6G.png)
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I meet too. This is my way to resolve.You can try.

http://note.heifahaizei.com/book/gitbook.html

```
info: installing plugin "mygitalk"
info: install plugin "mygitalk" (*) from NPM with version 0.2.6 
fetchMetadata -> resolveW / |######################################################---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
C:\Users\Fly\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\aproba\index.js:25
    if (args[ii] == null) throw missingRequiredArg(ii)
                          ^

Error: Missing required argument #1
    at andLogAndFinish (C:\Users\Fly\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
    at fetchPackageMetadata (C:\Users\Fly\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
    at resolveWithNewModule (C:\Users\Fly\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:490:12)
    at C:\Users\Fly\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:491:7
```

Comment: it didn't work for mathjax.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error:

```
info: installing 1 plugins using npm@3.9.2 
info:  
info: installing plugin "mathjax" 
info: install plugin "mathjax" (*) from NPM with version 1.1.2 
fetchMetadata → headers  
./.gitbook/versions/3.2.3/node_modules/npm/node_modules/aproba/index.js:25
      if (args[ii] == null) throw missingRequiredArg(ii)
```

I think it might be the plugin mathjax version too old. As you see 1.1.2.

I do these and it works

```
npm install mathjax@2.7.7
```

then change the book.json

```
{
  "plugins": ["mathjax-pro"]
}
```

then

```
gitbook install ./
```

Comment: It doesn't work right now. It raises the error `npm WARN ml No description
npm WARN ml No repository field.
npm WARN ml No license field.
`